# How to upgrade/update Selenium version of an existing Selenium Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium WebDriver project with eclipse IDE on Ubuntu 11 OS. I want to upgrade the java client driver from 2.24 to 2.25. How can I do this?

Comment: What eclipse plugin supports selenium? What eclipse integration platform has that plugin?

Comment: You don't need a plugin to use selenium webdriver functionality inside of eclipse. Though if you look in the Eclipse market place there is a plugin "Selenity" for selenium Grid.

Comment: If you use plugin then you have no problems with wrong version. Eclipse won't install that.

Comment: Such a plugin would ease the process. I have no idea if this is any good (and won't be testing it myself), but there is a eclipse selenium plugin on source forge http://seleniumeclipse.sourceforge.net/.
Also Netbeans has a plugin for selenium funny thing is one of the reasons I used eclipse over netBeans is because I thought eclipse had more plugin support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the java client driver from the selenium website (2.25.0) http://seleniumhq.org/download/ . Unpack the zip file to the dir of your choice.

Start-up eclipse and select the project you are working on. Add the latest selenium jar to the referenced lib by going to Properties->Java Build Path->Add External JARs (select the selenium jar). To do things in a clean way I removed the references to the other libs that had been there along with the older selenium (2.24) and replaced them with the new versions. You can find the new jars under selenium-2.25.0/libs folder. Add them the same way you added selenium-2.25.0.jar.

Note: This will break your project if you don't add the jar files correctly so you may want to create a backup of your project.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone that still coming here...

You can try and integrate to your project the [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) library.

It would easily allow you to automate the install process of different WebDriver implementations (binaries).

For example, for ChromeDriver:

```
ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup(); //downloading and installing ChromeDriver
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); //initializing ChromeDriver
```

If you use Maven, add it's dependency to your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
   <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```