# Upgrading Selenium 2.53 to 3.4.0

Tags: selenium, upgrade

What are all the steps I have to follow while upgrading to latest selenium version.

I am using Selenium 2.53 and configured the same in Eclipse. Changing just  selenium jar files will work? or any other process I have to follow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upgrade/update Selenium version of an existing Selenium Java project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294218/how-to-upgrade-update-selenium-version-of-an-existing-selenium-java-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow following steps:

1] Remove old Selenium jars by selecting from Properties->Java Build Path->Add External JARs

2] Download latest selenium jars from [Selenium download](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

3] Add the latest selenium jar to the referenced lib by going to Properties->Java Build Path->Add External JARs

4] Download latest Geckodriver from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

5] And rest things are same. Just you need to specify the Geckodriver path into your code like this :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\\\Library\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, this works well for me. Also, I would like to know one more thing. Similar to Gecko driver, do we have any drivers for Chrome and IE ? or existing one will work with 3.4.0

Comment: @Kumar Yes Chrome and IE do have drivers. You can download them from following link : http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have to upgrade your JDK from Java 7 to Java 8.

Once its done and environment variable and all things are properly configured for Java 8, then you can upgrade your Selenium related JAR files.

In addition to that you will also need latest geckodriver and latest version of Firefox browser(as older versions before 45 or so are not supported with geckodriver) to run your scripts properly in firefox browser.

Note : There is one known issue in Selenium 3,some interactions of actions class will not work in Firefox Browser. So If you don't have any problem with that then only upgrade to Selenium 3.